# Getting a ReadableStream from something that writes to WritableStreams

Tags: node.js, csv, stream, nodemailer

I've never used streams in Node.js, so I apologize in advance if this is trivial.

---

I'm using the `ya-csv` library to create a CSV. I use a line like this:

```
csvwriter = csv.createCsvStreamWriter(process.stdout)
```

As I understand it, this takes a writable `Stream` and writes to it when I add a record.

---

I need to use this CSV as an email attachment.

From `nodemailer`'s docs, here is how to do that:

```
attachments: [
    {   // stream as an attachment
        fileName: "text4.txt",
        streamSource: fs.createReadStream("file.txt")
    }
]
```

As I understand it, this takes a readable `Stream` and reads from it.

---

Therein lies the problem. I need a readable `Stream`, I need a writable `Stream`, but at no point do I have a `Stream`.

It would be nice if `ya-csv` had a:

```
csvwriter = csv.createReadableCsvStream()
```

But it doesn't. Is there some built-in stream that makes available for writing whatever it reads? I've looks for a library with no success (though there are a few things that could work but seem like overkill).

Answer (score 1):

you can use PassThrough stream for that:

```
var PassThrough = require('stream').PassThrough
var stream = new PassThrough
var csvwriter = csv.createCsvStreamWriter(stream)
```

now you can read from `stream` whatever is written

Comment: My passthrough buffer never fires an "end" event. I can't actually find anything in the `ya-csv` docs *or source* about how to specify that I've finished writing data, which is rather strange. Any ideas?

Comment: well, it looks like this this library is kind of crude. Try calling `end()` on `stream` explicilty.

Comment: It most certainly does. Unfortunately it seems to be the best option - AFAICT the only writing node-csv does is transforming existing CSVs, and if there is a better way it certainly isn't well documented.